# Angular httpPromise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a request function :

```
function search(request) {
    return $http.post('/path/to/resource', request);
}
```

I can call it like this :

```
search({/*...*/})
  .success(function() {})
  .error(function() {})
```

As I often need to find some objects by their ID, I need a shortcut function. I cannot find how to create this function so that I can also chain it with `success()` and `error()` functions.

I searched how to create a promise in angular and found the [documentation about $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and this is what I tried :

```
function searchById(id) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  search({id: id}).
    then(function (response) {
      deferred.resolve(response.data.results[0]);
    }, function (error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

I can only call it like this :

```
searchById().then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I would like to be able to call it like this :

```
searchById()
 .success(successCallback)
 .error(errorCallback);
```

The documentation about `$q` indicates that it returns a `promise` whereas the documentation about `$http` indicates that it returns an `httpPromise` but I cannot figure how to create an `httpPromise`.

Any idea?

Comment: `.success` and .`error` are being deprecated.  You should use the standard `.then` instead.

Comment: The $http service and $q uses the same type of promises inspired by Kris Kowal's Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular promises the error callback should be catch not error, try this

```
searchById()
 .then(successCallback)
 .catch(errorCallback);
```

sjokkogutten is correct that you don't need to use $q in this case you can simplify this

```
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  search({id: id}).
    then(function (response) {
      deferred.resolve(response.data.results[0]);
    }, function (error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
```

to this

```
return search({id: id}).
  then(function (response) {
  return response.data.results[0];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`$http` is already returning a promise, so there is no need to use `$q.defer()`. Also, `success()` and `error()` has been depreciated (since 1.4.4), you should use `then()` instead. 

Call your function like this:

```
search(request).then(function(data){
  // successcallback
}, function(error){
  // errorcallback
})
```

Comment: Instead of `then(success, error)`, much better to use `.then(...).catch(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a factory with $http functions will allow you to use `.success` and `.error`.  But you really should be using `.then`.

```
app.factory("dataService", function($http) {
    return {
        search: function() {
            return $http.get('path/to/api');
        },
        searchById: function(payload) {
            return $http.post('path/to/api', payload);
        },
        searchMoreThings: function(payload) {
            if(payload === "foo") payload = "bar";

            return $http.post('path/to/api', payload);
        }
    }
});
```

You can do:

```
dataService.searchById(searchTerm).success().error();
```

Comment: Ok for success/error deprecation, I will not use it. A point was unclear is my question : I also want to do some intermediate computation on the result before sending it to the "success" callback (where I call `deferred.resolve(response.data.results[0]);`). Can I include this computation without creating a new promise?

Comment: Why does computation need to be done **before** the success callback?  Can't you do it from within the callback itself?  i.e. `dataService.searchById(searchTerm).then(function(response) { /* do things to response.data */ }, function(response) { /* error */} );`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual example :

```
app.controller('controller',function($scope,$rootScope,$http,){
    $scope.login = function(request){
        var promise = $http.post(/path/to/resource, request, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function success(res){

                //it worked, you have data in res

        },function error(res){
            // it failed
        });
    };
});
```